# What can I do about my 2015 iMac getting very slow under load? Thermal paste?

Tags: imac, hardware

My Late 2015 27-inch iMac has been getting slower to run games over the last few years.  Now even Slack and Zoom cause problems.

Symptoms:

1. After running a Slack or Zoom call with multiple participants, the computer will slow down and grind to an almost halt.  If I Force Quit Slack/Zoom then it will recover over the next few minutes.
2. Works better in air-conditioned room or with fan directed at its back.
3. Recently had someone upgrade hard disk -> SSD and added RAM.  No effect on this problem.
4. During problems I can see that kernel_task is taking most CPU.  It does not do this normally.  I understand that kernel_task can mean many things, including that it is used to throttle the CPU in overheat situations.
5. During problems I can run `powermetrics` and see `Performance Limited Due to: CPU LIMIT PROCHOT`.  Normally it says `Performance Limited Due to: CPU LIMIT MAX_TURBO_LIMIT, CPU LIMIT TURBO_ATTENUATION`  I conclude that the performance has been limited because the CPU is too hot.
6. Fan doesn't normally run when load is light, but I can hear it during these problems.
7. Screenshots while Slack is working OK [image: Before critical.png], and then after a few minutes [image: Critical.png]

I saw this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yR3O63-OUw4), which says that thermal paste can get old and ineffective after a few years in these 27-inch iMacs.  I have now talked to two repairers who deny that this is possible.  One doesn't know what the problem is, and the other thinks I need to replace the CPU (which is otherwise working fine).  I can see that replacing the CPU would work if the thermal paste is the problem, since it would need to be done too.  But I don't want to spend time hunting around for this old CPU unnecessarily.

What can I do to get it working again?  I want to keep this computer as a second machine once I replace it, but I cannot replace it yet.  I once replaced the hard disk in a older mac, but this operation looks too risky for me to attempt it.

Comment: Have you checked for dust in and around the vents? Simple dust can accumulate and cause performance problems by trapping heat.

Comment: Asked tech who replaced drive and RAM to do look for dust.  He said it looked clean.

Comment: BTW, the command running on the right is `powermetrics`

Comment: It's quite common when replacing parts in those iMacs, to not reconnect heat sensors, which might cause problems with the machine's management of heat.